# Paper js добавление точки

Tags: javascript

Функция с ajax запросом присылает данные с сервера

```
function load3(){
 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'action.php',
  data: {
    'type': 'graf',
  },
  success: function(data) {
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

      if('success' in obj){
      var xz = obj.x;
      var yz = obj.y;
      }
    console.log('ajax'+xz);
    console.log('ajax'+yz);
    var point = new paper.Point(xz,yz);
    console.log('point'+point);
    path.lineTo(point.add([xz,yz]));
  }
  });
  }
```

Данные приходят верные, но в создании самой точки "y" почему то игнорируется и заместо него встает "x".
Консоль выводит c ajax
150,90 например, а переменная point (150,150)

Answer (score 0):

решил проблему напрямую посылая данные сюда

```
path.lineTo(point.add([xz,yz]));
```